# Laravel query builder with join and sorting on datetime

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables: users, user_detailes, activity.

Table: **user**

```
id          | username  | password  | firstname | lastname
1           | peter98   | ########  | Peter     | Parker
2           | john001   | ########  | John      | Doe
3           | kelly     | ########  | Kelly     | Johnson
```

Table: **user_detailes**

```
user_id     | age       | height    | hair_color
1           | 19        | 183       | Black
2           | 23        | 193       | Black
3           | 22        | 165       | Brown
```

Table: **activity**

```
user_id     | action    | description | timestamp
1           | SIGN_IN   | ########    | 2017-10-1 12:00:00
2           | SIGN_OUT  | ########    | 2017-10-1 10:00:00
1           | SIGN_OUT  | ########    | 2017-10-1 13:00:00
2           | SIGN_IN   | ########    | 2017-10-1 13:10:00
2           | SIGN_OUT  | ########    | 2017-10-1 13:30:00
```

I need a select statement with Laravel Query Builder or a SQL raw statement to get a user and his/her user_detailes and the last activity they did.

For example:

```
id          | firstname | lastname    | age     | hair_color    | last_action   | last_action_timestamp
1           | Peter     | Parker      | 19      | Black         | SIGN_OUT      | 2017-10-1 13:00:00
2           | John      | Doe         | 23      | Black         | SIGN_IN       | 2017-10-1 13:10:00
3           | Kelly     | Johnson     | 22      | Brown         | NULL          | NULL
```

I can't get my head around the join statement with the date sorting ;)

Comment: Is Eloquent allowed too?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is this as SQL query

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, ud.age, ud.hair_color, a.action, a.timestamp
FROM user u
INNER JOIN user_detailes ud ON u.id = ud.user_id
INNER JOIN activity a ON u.id = a.user_id
ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC
```

For a per User query I recommend using Eloquent instead

Comment: Could you help me with converting this raw query to a Laravel Quiery Builder: SELECT e.voornaam, s1.actie, s1.actie_timestamp
FROM users e
INNER JOIN personeel_planning s1
  ON (e.id = s1.user_id)
LEFT JOIN personeel_planning s2
  ON (e.id = s2.user_id AND s1.id < s2.id)
WHERE s2.id IS NULL;

Comment: You have to make a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as I can see you have one to one relationship between your user table and user_detailes table, and one to many relationships between user table and activity. that means if you join all of these tables you will have as result multi-row of one user with his user_detailes and activity because you have one to many relationships between user and activity tables. if you want to get all data like this, the query builder bellow can help you:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_detailes', 'users.id', '=', 'user_detailes.user_id')
        ->join('activity', 'users.id', '=', 'activity.user_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'contacts.*', 'orders.*')
        ->orderBy('activity.timestamp', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

and if you want to get user_detailes and activity data of one user by his id, just you need to add where a statement like this :

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_detailes', 'users.id', '=', 'user_detailes.user_id')
        ->join('activity', 'users.id', '=', 'activity.user_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'contacts.*', 'orders.*')
        ->where('users.id','=',$user_id)
        ->orderBy('activity.timestamp','desc')
        ->get();
```

I wish this  can help you

Comment: Could you help me with converting this raw query to a Laravel Quiry Builder?

SELECT e.voornaam, s1.actie, s1.actie_timestamp
FROM users e
INNER JOIN personeel_planning s1
  ON (e.id = s1.user_id)
LEFT JOIN personeel_planning s2
  ON (e.id = s2.user_id AND s1.id < s2.id)
WHERE s2.id IS NULL;

Comment: first of all, please validate my response if it's help you.